# Adding dict keys that have a specific value to an array in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I searched around and can't seem to figure out the syntax for doing this.

I have a dictionary and I'm trying to add all the keys that have a specific value (xColor) to my Python list (list). I know that values() and keys() don't take any arguments, but I don't know how to iterate through the elements in my dict (tile) to do what I need.

Here is my attempt:

```
for colors in tile.values():
   for cords in tile.keys():
      if tile.values(colors) == xColor:
         list.append(tile.keys(cords))
      else:
         return
```

And just for reference,

```
xColor = 'pink' 
tile = {(0,0): 'pink', ...} 
tile.keys() = [(0,0), ...]
tile.values() = ['pink',...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you really should read [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) in the tutorial, because it explains things like "how to iterate through the elements of my dict".

But briefly, you can iterate through the keys just by using the dict itself as an iterator, and you can iterate through the key-value pairs by using the `items()` or `iteritems()` methods.

Your code is iterating through the values, and then, for each one, iterating through the keys. There's no reason for that. You want the keys that go with certain values; you don't care about any other keys. Also, your function is going to `return` (meaning it stops both loops, and returns a useless `None` after all that work you did building up a list) as soon as you get a failed match.

You can fix your code in one of two ways:

```
matches = []
for cord, color in tile.iteritems():
    if color == xColor:
        matches.append(cord)
return matches
```

Or:

```
matches = []
for cord in tile:
    color = tile[cord]
    if color == xColor:
        matches.append(cord)
return matches
```

The two are basically equivalent. Looking up `tile[cord]` to get `color` is simple, and very cheap.

If you know anything about list comprehensions, you may recognize the pattern in the first one as exactly what a list comprehension does. So you can convert the whole thing it to a one-liner:

```
return [cord for cord, color in tile.iteritems() if color == xColor]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `list.extend` method with generator, extracting required keys:

```
In [9]: d = {(0, 0): 'pink', (0, 1): 'pink', (2, 3): 'blue', (3, 2): 'red'}

In [10]: x_color = 'pink'

In [11]: [k for (k, v) in d.iteritems() if v == x_color]
Out[11]: [(0, 1), (0, 0)]

In [12]: l = [(2, 4)]

In [13]: l.extend(k for (k, v) in d.iteritems() if v == x_color)

In [14]: l
Out[14]: [(2, 4), (0, 1), (0, 0)]
```